# Question about Impedance/ Admittance

Tags: impedance

I have a question about impedance and imaginary numbers:

I have admittance value as like this,

Y(iw) = j Im[Y(iw)] with Re[Y(iw)] = 0.

Then, can we write, Z(iw) as below,

Z(iw) = j /  Im[Y(iw)]

Answer (score 1):

No, 1/j = -j.

So if Y= jK(w), then Z = -j/K(w)